# wordpress orderby=rand unless ACF filed = true

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This may sound like a bit of a bizarre question but..

I have a client who has requested that post results be sorted randomly (easy peasy).. but they also want to be able to select posts to be "featured" and appear at the top of the list with the other posts sorted randomly underneath.

I've tried having one loop with the following:

```
<?php global $query_string; query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' );
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (get_field('featured_listing') == 1):?>
         list of featured posts
    <?php endif ;?>
    <?php if (get_field('featured_listing') != 1):?>
         all the other posts posts
    <?php endif ;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But featured posts and non featured posts were all ordered randomly together.

I then tried creating two queires:

```
<?php  global $query_string; query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' );
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (get_field('featured_listing') == 1):?>
           list of featured posts
    <?php endif ;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' );
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (get_field('featured_listing') != 1):?>
          all the other posts posts
    <?php endif ;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when the page loads they all still load as one random list. If you refresh the page a couple of times the featured posts appear at the top of the list but that's not really much good.

Is this an ACF issue or have I overlooked something really simple? Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts()`. It breaks the main query object which in turn breaks thousands of other functions that relies on the main query object. Also, your one query is breaking the other one. Apart from breaking stuff, `query_posts()` are really slow and reruns queries, which slows your page which means a bad SEO ranking. I do not know on which page you use this, but you can always modify the main query's query vars with `pre_get_posts` , or if you really really need a custom query, use `WP_Query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use `query_posts()`. It is a really really bad way to query the db for posts. If you need to alter the main query (except on true pages), you should use `pre_get_posts`, otherwise, if you really need a custom query, use `WP_Query`.

To solve your issue, simply rerun the same loop, once to output featured posts, the second time to display the rest

```
$args = [
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    // Any other arguments
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    // Run the loop for the first time to show featured posts
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // Get the field value
        $field = get_field( 'featured_listing', get_the_ID() );
        if ( true === $field ) { // Featured posts
            // Output featured posts
            the_title();
        }

    } // endwhile, end of loop one

    // Rewind the loop to run it again
    $q->rewind_posts();

    // Run the loop for the second time to show other posts
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // Get the field value
        $field = get_field( 'featured_listing', get_the_ID() );
        if ( true !== $field ) { // Other posts
            // Output other posts
            the_title();
        }

    } // endwhile, end of loop
    wp_reset_postdata(); // EXTREMELE IMPORTANT FOR CUSTOM LOOPS
} //endif
```

### EDIT

As I said, if you need to alter the main query, use `pre_get_posts`. As this is `category.php`, you definitely do not want to replace the main query with a custom one. We need to alter the main query vars before the main query runs.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only target the front end
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        // Set our custom ordering to random
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
});
```

This will set ordering on the category pages to random. All we need to do now is to remove the custom query and replace it with the default loop

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    // Run the loop for the first time to show featured posts
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Get the field value
        $field = get_field( 'featured_listing', get_the_ID() );
        if ( true === $field ) { // Featured posts
            // Output featured posts
            the_title();
        }

    } // endwhile, end of loop one

    // Rewind the loop to run it again
    rewind_posts();

    // Run the loop for the second time to show other posts
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Get the field value
        $field = get_field( 'featured_listing', get_the_ID() );
        if ( true !== $field ) { // Other posts
            // Output other posts
            the_title();
        }

    } // endwhile, end of loop
} //endif
```

Comment: This has the same issue as above in that it doesnt like the custome field.  I've tried adding the field's meta_key and meta_value into the array which returns the correct result but it's now returning EVERYTHING with the value 1 regardless of category.  Is there an easy way to get the category ID in to the array?

Comment: On which page/template is this exactly

Comment: its on category.php so the url is something like ../category/suppliers/

Comment: AHA, then you should not be using a custom query at all. Will update my answer

Comment: The random works fine but the ACF featured listing is still not playing ball. I wondered if it's because the ACF true/false statement doesnt return a value for false, only for true. but it's the true statement that's not showing up so I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Do `var_dump(get_field( 'featured_listing', get_the_ID() ) );` and make sure about your values.

Comment: It only bloody works!! :) Replaced the 1 with true and it works!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could save the values in variables so you can build up the data/code and output it grouped in the order you need, for example...

***Updated to show some better (not perfect) code***

```
<?php
// Declare the variables
$featured_posts = null;
$other_posts = null;

// Define our arguments
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

// Now get the posts
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check we have some posts
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    // Then loop through them
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Build up your lists - add in whatever you need - title shown as an example
        if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'featured_listing', true ) == 1) {
            $featured_posts .= '<h2>'.get_the_title().'<h2>';
        } else {
            $other_posts .= '<h2>'.get_the_title().'<h2>';
        }
    }

} else {
    // no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // As Pieter says it is important to reset the post data

// Now output the lists in featured at the top
echo $featured_posts;
echo $other_posts;
?>
```

Comment: Might be a good idea. Even better idea would be to run the loop outputting the featured posts, `rewind_posts()` and rerun the loop again to display other posts. Just a **HHHHUUUUUUGGGGGEEEEE** tip, never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object which in turn breaks thousand of other functions and plugins that relies on the integrity of the main query object

Comment: Agree with the query_posts - I was just using what they had to avoid completely writing code for them. I think one query is fine if you want a mixed amount of "featured posts" however if you are happy with a set amount (4 featured and 6 other) then you could use two queries. Either way yes use wp_query() https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query if you plan on making custom queries.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems a much better way of achiving what I need. Although, I now have the issue that WP_Query ignores the custom fields query and doesnt output the featured_posts.

Comment: Do you mean that get_field('featured_listing') is no longer working?

Comment: Thats correct. I've tried a few variations on the custom field. It seems to be a common issue with ACF and WP_Query.

Comment: Have you tried `if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'featured_listing', true ) == 1)` for the query - I am afraid I don't use ACF so I am not sure how it works with its custom fields.